# Naming of elements 113, 115, 117, and 118

Tags: elements

Does anyone know of a blog, website, news server, or listserv to which one may subscribe to be notified when these elements get their official names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this press release](http://iupac.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Press-Release_Naming-Four-New-Elements_8June2016.pdf) from 8 June 2016, IUPAC proposes names for the four new elements as follows:

> nihonium and symbol Nh, for the element 113,
>
> moscovium and symbol Mc, for the element 115,
>
> tennessine and symbol Ts, for the element 117, and
>
> oganesson and symbol Og, for the element 118.

The public review (comments by 8 November 2016) of the provisional recommendations can be found [here](http://iupac.org/recommendation/names-and-symbols-of-the-elements-with-atomic-numbers-113-115-117-and-118/).

Comment: Take *that*, tosylate users.

Answer (score 7):

IUPAC will certainly have a press release on their news page, given that they are officially responsible for the names.

Currently, that's at this address: http://www.iupac.org/news/latest-news.html

Sadly, they don't appear to have an RSS feed. (Not even an Atom feed *[rimshot noise]*.)

Comment: I guess I could change my morning routine to include a visit to this page.